# How do I update a flash game on my website

Tags: actionscript-3

I've created a game in FlashDevelop IDE. I put the html and swf file on my server and my game plays perfectly off the website. However, I can't get it to update. After making changes, I delete the old swf file, generate a new one, and re-upload it, but it is still the same old version when I navigate to the site. Any thoughts?

Comment: ... clear the cache of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

The super simple way is to update a GET param on your flash file for every update you make.

Instead of requesting `mygame.swf`, you'd request `mygame.swf?version=1`, and when updated `mygame.swf?version=1.2` etc.

This would mean that the browsers would think that this is a new swf file (even though it isn't) and force them to redownload it.

Comment: This is a good idea during development, but once a version has been released this logic should be removed (else every client will download a new copy of the potentially large SWF each time they visit).

Comment: @Marty If the clients didn't download a new copy you could risk that they play old versions of the game. Whether they download a new copy because of a different GET param, or whether they do because they've cleared their cache (yeah, right), they still redownload the potentially large SWF file just once (as the GET param is the same. It's not the same as `mygame.swf?version=<?=rand()?>`. :-)

Comment: Sorry, you're right. For some reason I read your answer as using the rand/time method.